# SQL Server build dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I have a temp table called  `#temp`, and I need to get all the `CDate` column from that table, to build a string.

The `CDate` list in that table is (20171209, 20171210....20171223)

I expected to see

```
'A.[20171209] as [20171209], A.[20171210] as [20171210], 
 A.[20171211] as [20171211], A.[20171212] as [20171212], 
 A.[20171213] as [20171213], A.[20171214] as [20171214], 
 A.[20171215] as [20171215], A.[20171216] as [20171216], 
 A.[20171217] as [20171217], A.[20171218] as [20171218], 
 A.[20171219] as [20171219], A.[20171220] as [20171220], 
 A.[20171221] as [20171221], A.[20171222] as [20171222], 
 A.[20171223] as [20171223], '
```

however the result I got is missing the first date , ie 'A.[20171209] as [20171209]'

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT 
     @col2 = ISNULL(@col2 + 'A.' + QUOTENAME(CDate) + ' as ' + QUOTENAME(CDate) + ', '  , '') 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CDate FROM #temp) AS tmp;
```

Comment: You need to concat: `SELECT @col2 += ...` (Make sure you assign `''` when you declare the variable else you will get NULL)

Comment: @AlexK. - `@col2 +=..` is same as `@col2 = @col2  +..` That is not the problem

Comment: Yea, but that's not equivalent to the posted SQL

Comment: @AlexK. - It is.`@col2 = ISNULL(@col2 + 'A.' ..`

Comment: but if its null @col2 is overwritten with ''

Comment: @AlexK. - My bad...yeah first record will not be part of concatenation

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach will not work in some cases, it is an undocumented feature, always use `For Xml path` to concatenating the rows into csv.

```
SET @col2 = stuff((SELECT ', A.' + Quotename(CDate) + ' as '
                    + Quotename(CDate) 
             FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT CDate
                     FROM   #temp) a
             FOR xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks!! Is there anyway to remove the last ',' directly?